# Getting trouble after update R in ubuntu

Tags: r, linux

I'm having trouble after upgrading R in my laptop with Ubuntu.

Some packages, for instance "readr" give me this log, when I try to reinstall it:

```
> install.packages("~/Downloads/readr_1.3.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘readr’ ...
** package ‘readr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Collector.cpp -o Collector.o

In file included from /home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp:33:0,
                 from /home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/container/string.hpp:26,
                 from boost.h:9,
                 from QiParsers.h:4,
                 from DateTimeParser.h:6,
                 from Collector.h:5,
                 from Collector.cpp:4:

/home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/container/detail/type_traits.hpp:64:29: error: ‘boost::move_detail::nat2’ has not been declared
 using ::boost::move_detail::nat2;
                             ^
/home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/container/detail/type_traits.hpp:65:29: error: ‘boost::move_detail::nat3’ has not been declared
 using ::boost::move_detail::nat3;
                             ^
In file included from /home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base_std_atomic.hpp:18:0,
                 from /home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_counted_base.hpp:48,
                 from /home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/shared_count.hpp:29,
                 from /home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:28,
                 from /home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from boost.h:11,
                 from QiParsers.h:4,
                 from DateTimeParser.h:6,
                 from Collector.h:5,
                 from Collector.cpp:4:

/home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BH/include/boost/detail/sp_typeinfo.hpp:23:82: note: #pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/core/typeinfo.hpp> instead.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:177: recipe for target 'Collector.o' failed
make: *** [Collector.o] Error 1

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘readr’
* removing ‘/home/adeilson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/readr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/home/adeilson/Downloads/readr_1.3.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I edited your post. You wanted ``` not `\\\`.  (And I didn't downvote.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I install the packages that give me trouble by using the terminal. Try running:

```
sudo apt install r-cran-readr
```

Comment: I did, it came with: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package r-cran-readr

Comment: Google the term 'Rutter PPA c2d4u or look at the top of the [README at CRAN](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html). I also have several posts (and videos) on topic below http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/code/r4/ (and scroll down a little).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the question by myself. Only made the "source code" url from CRAN at my system settings.

Now, all the packages are installing with no problem...